# How can I open the window when it's dark outside without fearing that moths might fly in?

Tags: home, pest-control, summer

I have a mottephobia (a fear of moths) and when it's too warm in my room in the night I can't just open the window. My Screen is way too bright. Is there any way to open the window by night and nothing flies in?

Comment: At my house, every window has a screen. Moths can't get in unless I open those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During a camping trip, I had seen the camp guy place a pan/plate filled with water, right under a light.

Being the only light source in the room, the moths came in and many got tricked and dived into the water.

But a window net screen is best solution

Comment: This is... brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

In India, open spaces with greenery translate to two things:

1. great view to look at during the day
2. mosquitoes rushing in to your house by the night

You could try buying stick-on nets for your windows. These have adhesive backing velcro frame that you can stick on the borders of your window frames (you have to keep the window open all the time though) and then stick on the net. This means you will fresh air and no bugs by the night.

Also see [this google search query](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=window%20netting&num=100&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=MfViVbeBIoy8uATu44GoCA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1916&bih=941)

Answer (score 3):

Light temperature makes a huge difference. If you are using compact fluorescent lamps, make sure you are using those with "yellow light" (2700 Kelvin).In the case of incandescente lamp, you  can use a 220V lamp on a 127V instalation the light will attract way less insects (moth included).

This will not prevent any moths but will reduce a lot their presence.

Comment: You can use [F.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) to do the same to your computer screens at night.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a hack answer, but I've got the same problem, I hate them in the house. I never open a window at night when the lights are on unless its one of the windows covered either in net curtain (which prevents most of them getting in, not necessarily all, depends how bright the light is in the room) or an insect screen. Both of which you'd have to buy...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if darkening your screen is not a option:

- Take a cloth and pin that up in window. This can be achieved with tacks, tape or etc.
- This is not a hack, but investing in other cooling options would be wise.
- Having a fan facing the window also helps. As this gives the insects something to fly against and makes it harder for them to enter.

Comment: A window-mounted fan, while not very hacky, could cover all three of these!

Answer (score 1):

I've had success in tricking flies into leaving a room by turning on a light in the hallway. You may be able to distract (a percentage of) the moths by installing a more moth-attractive light somewhere outside.

Answer (score -1):

I spray around the window frames periodically with bug spray.  Does a good enough job for me ( a few hours in the evening watching TV with windows open)...a more permanent solution may be required for others!